# How to enforce array initializer having same number of items as array size?

Tags: c++

I recently discovered this bug:

```
enum class MyEnum
{
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3,
    Count
};
const char* names[MyEnum::Count] =
{
    "Enum1",
    "Enum2",
};

static_assert(sizeof_array(names) == MyEnum::Count, "Name count mismatch");
```

The `static_assert` here will **never** assert unless you change `names[MyEnum::Count]` to `names[]`, which I did.

Is there a way to enforce or detect whether an array with an explicit size and initializer actually initializes the whole array, in order to prevent this type of bug?

Comment: This behaviour is by-design (the array is correctly sized, the other elements’ values are just undefined). If you want ”correct” String representations of enum members use a nameof macro library or use something like T4.

Comment: Why do you need to use `[MyEnum::Count]` instead of just `[]` as long as you have the assert to catch missing values?

Comment: I changed the problematic instance in this case to just `[]` but there are many other places in the codebase that use hardcoded sizes [4] which are harder to check individually.

We also use M4 to generate enums in most cases, but there are cases where arrays of structs must match some enum size, and other more complicated cases than just stringifying an enum.

Comment: @Dai "_the other elements’ values are just undefined_" Correction: the other elements' values are default initialized.

Comment: You could assert (at run-time) that last element does not contains unintended 0. Unit test could also be used for that purpose. But as already suggested, using [] would be the correct solution. By specifying the size, you tell the compiler that you need so much space even if there are less element. If there are too much elements, you would probably get a warning.

Comment: If you are willing to switch to `std::array` or something equivalent, it should be trivial to write either a function or constructor that tests this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some messy code to check for this will prevent the bug from reappearing in the same place but won't prevent similar bugs in other places.
If this is what you want, consider adding a good comment instead:

```cpp
// `names[]` is correct, changing it to `names[X]` is a mistake, refer to #123.
const char* names[] = { /* ... */ };
```

If you have similar code like that in many places, consider writing a custom clang tidy check.

I've never written a custom clang tidy check myself, but it seems to be doable and sounds like a good long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::array`, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t typename Cont, std::size_t ... Is>
auto make_array_impl(const Cont& c, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array{c[Is]...};
}

template <std::size_t Expected, typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> make_array(const T(&a)[N])
{
    static_assert(Expected == N);
    return make_array_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

auto names = make_array<MyEnum::Count>({
    "Enum1",
    "Enum2",
}); // Assert fire at compile time
```

Without modifying your code, you have to found a linter with that warning, or write your own rule (clang tooling might help).